# Find a specific data from MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a user table with column ID and names. All of the ID's data starts with KM followed by 5 characters of number for example KM00001 (7 characters total). I want to make a search query where if the ID is typed in, it will only search in the ID column and if not it will automatically search in the name column.

```
if(isset($_POST['find'])) {
    $find = $_POST['find'];

    $query2 = mysqli_query($condb,"SELECT * FROM students WHERE id LIKE '$find' ");
    $query = mysqli_fetch_array($query2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to check if the input matches your predetermined ID format, and pick which column to search based on whether that's true or false.

In PHP, the command `preg_match` is used to check against regular expressions, so your script would look something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['find'])) {
    $find = $_POST['find'];

    if (preg_match('/^KM\d{5}$/i', $find)) {
        $column = 'id';
    }
    else {
        $column = 'name';
    }

    $query2 = mysqli_query($condb,"SELECT * FROM students WHERE $column LIKE '$find' ");
    $query = mysqli_fetch_array($query2);
}
```

(In the regular expression `/^KM\d{5}$/i`, "KM" are literal characters, \d matches any digit, {5} specifies that we want five digits, bookending that between ^ (beginning of string) and $ (end of string) ensures it only matches if the whole input string is an ID, and the "i" flag at the end makes the search case-insensitive.)